# React documentation - JSX Prevents Injection Attacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-injection

I am learning REACT JS using their own documentation. And when i came to a section [JSX Prevents Injection Attacks](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-prevents-injection-attacks), I got confused about this topic. how JSX prevents from injection attacks?
Can anyone explain me on this, please.

The said text in documentation about the topic is:

> It is safe to embed user input in JSX.
>
> ```
> const title = response.potentiallyMaliciousInput;
> // This is safe:
> const element = <h1>{title}</h1>;
> ```
>
> By default, React DOM escapes any values embedded in JSX before rendering them. Thus it ensures that you can never inject anything that’s not explicitly written in your application. Everything is converted to a string before being rendered. This helps prevent XSS (cross-site-scripting) attacks.

Comment: So did you read that? What is still unclear?

Comment: What specifically don't you understand about the documentation you quoted?

Comment: How it actually preventing from injection attacks?

Comment: If a user provides the input `<script src="http://example.com/malicious-script.js"></script>`, the rendered output will have those actual characters (the `<`, `s`, `c`, etc.) instead of including and running the malicious script.

Comment: XSS = executable code injection. react injects only non-code (eg HTML-attributes/classes and text) unless you do hacky things. if you try to inject code, it will simply be rendered as text, but not executed. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Phil,   So in the above comment he has stated that while trying to load the malicious file, react only treat that as a text not as a resource file that has to be loaded. Correct?

Comment: @Subin - It doesn't load the resource **at all**. You get those actual characters in the text. For instance, suppose you had: `<div>The user said: {userContent}</div>` and `userContent` had the text I quoted above in it. The result would be a div with the **text** `The user said: <script src="http://example.com/malicious-script.js"></script>` **not** `The user said` followed by an actual script element.

Comment: Kk now i understood. But i  have a doubt, if the attacker wants to load the malicious file into the code, why he cant make it directly into the HTML file. like inserting a script tag..

Comment: @Subin - I suggest reading up on XSS. The point isn't to hack the page in your *own* browser, the point is to provide content that the site will render in a page in someone *else's* browser. If the site doesn't avoid XSS attacks, user A can inject a script into user B's session.

Comment: @Subin, try fixing this (and other) questions by making them clearer or contribute to Stack Overflow through other means (answering questions, for example) in order to restore a good account standing.

Answer (score 7):

Because JSX renders text as text, HTML in user input is not treated as HTML, just as plain text. An example is probably the simplest way to show this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userContent: `So I told the guy <script src="http://example.com/malicious-script.js><\/script>`
        };
    }
    
    render() {
        return <div>User content: {this.state.userContent}</div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Notice how the script tag is rendered as text. It doesn't create a script element, it's just characters (`<`, `s`, `c`, `r`, etc.).